# CORS access for HttpListener

Tags: c#, cors, httplistener

I have a C# console app, running an `HttpListener`, and my clients are getting denied because of CORS.

How do I set `Access-Allow-All-Origins` to `*` with my setup?

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/");
listener.Start();

    public static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListenerContext context = Program.listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        if (request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        }
        response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        NameValueCollection coll = request.QueryString;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(coll["name"]) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(coll["ext"]))
        {
            response.StatusCode = 400;
            response.ContentType = "text/html";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                writer.WriteLine("Missing parameters in queryString. Send 'name' and 'ext'");
            response.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Program.nameResDictionary.Add(coll["name"] + "." + coll["ext"], response);
            using (var outp = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Program.inDir,coll["name"] + "." + coll["ext"])))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(outp);
            }

            toLog.Add("File " + coll["name"] + "." + coll["ext"] + " added");
        }
        stream.Close();
        request.InputStream.Close();
        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
    }
```

Comment: Your code seem to try to set the header twice on OPTIONS and potentially do more stuff for OPTIONS... I'd use Fiddler and watch if responses from your server make sense... Also check if browsers shows anything in debug console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use JSONP in your ajax calls as below :

```
 $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossdomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ServiceURL,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: { Param1 : 'Test'},
        success: function (data) {
        }
```

and your handler will look like this :

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string callback = context.Request.QueryString["callback"];
            string Param1 = context.Request.QueryString["Param1"];
            object dataToSend = null;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string JSONstring = js.Serialize(dataToSend);
            string JSONPstring = string.Format("{0}({1});", callback, JSONstring);
            context.Response.Write(JSONPstring);
        }
```

the above code is converting the response to JSONP.
the callback parameter is automatically added by the ajax call and should be returned to the client

Comment: JSONP is in fact a simpler approach, but this accepted answer does not answer the question that was asked. A preferred answer should describe how to allow the HttpListener to respond in a way that will allow the CORS.

Answer (score 16):

Based on the OPTIONS responses I saw coming back from some other CORS stuff we're doing in IIS, the following worked for me with `HttpListener`. These values may not be exactly right for you, but should get you going in the right direction.

```
if (request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
}
response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```